# Math.random() help get '+N' and '-N' randoms ( excluding specific range )

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, random

I need a little help with **Math.random()**:
I have to rotate some images (with CSS3 transform (deg) )
 in the way to get results from `-40` to `+40`
**but skipping results from range: *-20* and *+20***

[image: math random defined + - radius]

If I'm not wrong this will get me random results in a range from **-40** to **+40**

```
  var counter = Math.round(Math.random()*81)-40;
```

How to exclude from the results numbers between -20 and +20 ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modifying existing answers to give a uniform distribution range -40 to -21 and 21 to 40:

```
(Math.random()<.5?-1:1)*(Math.floor(Math.random()*20) + 21)
```

Comment: So, just to make a resume: if states `*21` than the results are... ? 40 - 21, right?!

Comment: -40 to -20 and 20 to 40: (Math.random()<.5?-1:1)*(Math.floor(Math.random()*21) + 20)   ||||||    -40 to -21 and 21 to 40: (Math.random()<.5?-1:1)*(Math.floor(Math.random()*20) + 21)  Answer clearly states it is the range requested now, I think.

Comment: Right, I do NOT need the +|- **20**, just from 21 to 40! great job user12861!

Answer (score 13):

Random -1 or 1 times 0-20 random plus 20, could work

```
(Math.random()<.5?-1:1)*Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 21);
```

Sample Results from 1300 runs (showing only positive for simplicity):

```
Number_21: 70
Number_22: 62
Number_23: 56
Number_24: 57
Number_25: 79
Number_26: 57
Number_27: 64
Number_28: 60
Number_29: 57
Number_30: 67
Number_31: 63
Number_32: 81
Number_33: 81
Number_34: 65
Number_35: 59
Number_36: 59
Number_37: 62
Number_38: 71
Number_39: 52
Number_40: 78
```

Comment: Math.random() returns a floating point number between 0 and 1 inclusive. So if Math.random() is less than 0.5 return a negative 1, otherwise return 1. Basically it allows for approximately half the run of this code will be multiplied by a negative one.

Comment: Not really, no. If you want integers for the readability then you could use Math.round, but it's not needed.

Comment: This solution has the same problem as Xeon06's.  -40, -20, 20, and 40 are given half as frequently as the other integers.  So it's not a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 10):

I would have a random number between 20 and 40 generated, then randomly negate it.

```
var counter = (Math.round(Math.random() * 20) + 20) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the delay I was testing.  The question doesn't say, but when giving a "random" answer I think a uniform distribution should be expected unless otherwise noted.  This solution gets -40, -20, 20, and 40 half as often as the other integers in the range.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty interesting. I suck at probabilities. +1'd your answer

Answer (score 7):

Without branches and only a **single** `random()` call, using the magic of the modulus operator:

```
//Return a result between -40 and +40, excluding the range -20 to +20
var zeroToThirtyNine = Math.floor(Math.random()*40)
var counter = ((zeroToThirtyNine+61)%81)-40
```

```
zeroToThirtyNine | counter
---------------------------
               0 | 21
               1 | 22
               2 | 23
                ...
              18 | 39
              19 | 40
              20 | -40
              21 | -39
                ...
              37 | -23
              38 | -22
              39 | -21
```

Comment: +1 Interesting how many approaches to a same problem! Great answer!

Comment: cool idea - should also be the fastest solution here, because it avoids any processor pipeline flushes

Comment: @Heinzi: A second call to `Math.Random()` is going to be several **orders of magnitude** slower than a pipeline-flush...

Answer (score 6):

Generate numbers between -20 and +20, then if negative, subtract another twenty degrees.  If positive, add twenty degrees.

Also, you probably want floor instead of round so you won't get 41 degrees.

```
var counter = Math.floor(Math.random()*81)-40;
```

Comment: If using `Math.round(Math.random() * x)`, the highest value you'll ever get is `x`.

Comment: Thanks Xeon06 ! I think I'm getting the point of the **extra '1'** floating around... just dusturbing the count...

Answer (score 4):

There are 40 possible numbers you want to generate (-40 to -21, 21 to 40- these are both 20-number ranges) -> generate a random uniformly distributed number in [0,39] (which also contains 40 numbers). This can be done in Javascript by Math.floor(Math.random()*40)

Map the output range to the range you want.

For instance:

```
var uniformFrom0To39 = Math.floor(Math.random()*40)
return uniformFrom0To39 <= 19 ? uniformFrom0To39 - 40 : uniformFrom0To39 + 1
```

You could also perform the mapping using an array, [-40, -39, ..., -21, 21, 22, ..., 40]- you could also interpret that implementation as "create an array with the values you want and choose one at random".

Answer (score 3):

Your code is giving random numbers between -40 and +41, because Math.round() could round up.
The following code should give, what you want:

```
if(Math.random()>0.5) {
    counter = Math.round(Math.random()*19)-40 // from -40 to -21
} else {
    counter = Math.round(Math.random()*19)+21 //from +21 to +40
}
```

Comment: Also a non-uniform distribution.  -40, -21, 21, and 40 occur half as often as others.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a less-symmetrical area of exclusion, you could do the randomization like so:

```
do
{
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*81 - 40);
}
while ((randomNum < excludedMax) && (randomNum > excludedMin));
```

This will work nice if you wanted to exclude, say, -19 to 4 or something else odd.  It would also work nice for your case.

Comment: If the area of exclusion is larger than the area of acceptable numbers, this approach could be very slow.

Comment: For sure.  It is just very simple, readable, and easy to modify the values and still understand.  Definitely not optimized, though.

Answer (score -1):

Write a loop that loops until you get a number that's outside the range.  It's easy to understand, and easy to prove that the number you get is still random.

Comment: wait wait wait! How exactly? this is interesting! Thanks for your time

Comment: pseudocode:while the random number is between -20 and 20, random again.

Comment: Inefficient and overly complex on the down side.  I do like easy to understand though.